# Fastest way to detect major color(s) in an image?

Tags: image

I'm not particularly keen on the language or library to use but the tool that gets the job done well and fast enough. Or perhaps the algorithm or approach to use.

Any tip, advice code samples , URL links is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Select a pixel at random.  It's colour is the major colour in your image. This is relatively quick and wildly hopeless.

Select 2 pixels, at random.  Take the 'mode colour' of these two.  A bit slower, less wildly hopeless.

Select 3 pixels, ...

you can see where this is going

Answer (score 1):

One way I've done this in the past is to take the image and reduce it to a 1x1 image that will give you the most used color, or a 2x2 for a presentation of the most used color in each quadrant and up from there. It's not particularly good but it's the fastest method I could think of.

Comment: What if I want to exclude the "background" color in the image. Example will be detecting the color of a car in an image.

Comment: Then you're getting into algorithms that are on the level with what the best engineers at Adobe have been struggling to perfect for the last couple decades. Beyond my capabilities

Comment: @shawndreck If you can assume that the background colour is always in a certain place (top left or top right), that might help you out. If you're looking for something that looks nice, though, it is a lot more complicated as OriginalSyn mentions.

Comment: @OriginalSyn Hannele , Thanks buddies! Do you guys happen to have any experience with openCV??

Answer (score 1):

With the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm), you could convert the image to a limited palette, then ask it for the colours. Something like (haven't tested the following):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("foo.jpg")
im = im.convert("P", Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=16)
```

With `Image.ADAPTIVE`, `im.convert` will select the 16 most common colours, also known as a *palette*. Then, you should be able to access them using `im.palette`.